# Visual Basic Program Exit Button

Tags: vb.net, exit

I am trying to make one of the forms in my Visual Basic (Microsoft Visual Studio 2017) program open another form when someone clicks on the red exit button at the top right of the actual window, but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone please help? Is it possible?

Comment: Ask somebody else to run your program, even though it isn't finished.  Creating a new window when the user closes one is pretty courageous, you want to make sure it doesn't confuse the dickens out of your user.  Something like a "Next>" button tends to be a lot less surprising.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Dim frm As New Form1  
      frm.Show()            

      Me.Close()
 End Sub
```

Comment: It is more likely that the OP want to use the [Form.Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) event, as in `Private Sub SomeFormName_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing`.

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the actual problem. that the OP has.

Answer (score 0):

Like Andrew mentioned you are likely looking to utilize the Form.Closing event. This is helpful to fire actions when your program closes.

However this will also exit your program i.e. you're second form will pop up for a split second and then the entire program will close. Therefore you'll likely also then want to use the [Form.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) method to bring up the second form. This will prevent your program from exiting until the second form is closed.

See below. Add this sub to your first form.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Closing(Sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        Form2.ShowDialog()

    End Sub
```